# Rails CSV upload with validations on fields populating db with only certain rows of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I upload a csv file with multiple rows of data, some of which are valid(based on my validations in my model) and some aren't, my database gets populated with the entries that are valid even though there exists rows with invalid data in the csv file.

What should I do to reject the entire csv file once an invalid field is found? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your entire call in a transaction. Let's say your model is User :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    CSV.each do |l|
        a = User.new(l)
        if !a.save
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
     end
   end
end
```